# C function returning the string length

Tags: c, function

I do not want the string length to display when I use a put or printf inside a function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Entre(int x, int lim_inf, int lim_sup)
{
    int n;
    if (lim_inf <= x && x <= lim_sup)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
        return printf("X não está entre lim_inf e lim_sup");
}

main()
{
    int numx, numinf, numsup;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &numx, &numinf, &numsup);

    printf("%d", Entre(numx, numinf, numsup));
}
```

I tried to change put or printf function but it continues to display the string length (or what I think it is)

Comment: have you considered a struct that has the `int` (return value of `Entre`) and another `int` (or boolean) that indicated whether the `else`  branch is entered for the calling values?

Comment: Why do you return the value from `puts`?

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the text *as text* into it.

Comment: As for your problem, what do you think that [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) return? Why do you think that value would be correct to return from the `Entre` function? See also the comment by @stark.

Comment: @stark I want to return a string to indicate that the number in x isn't between inf e sup. It's not correct to do this inside the function Entre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return printf, it prints "X não está entre lim_inf e lim_sup" then returns the number of characters printed, 34, which you print with

```
printf("%d", Entre(numx, numinf, numsup))
```

if you want to avoid printing the length of the string, then you could:

A) Refactor function Entre to return a boolean

```
bool Entre(int x, int lim_inf, int lim_sup)
{
    int n;
    if (lim_inf <= x && x <= lim_sup)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
         return false;
}
```

B) Print "X não está entre lim_inf e lim_sup" and then return some value

```
int Entre(int x, int lim_inf, int lim_sup)
{
    int n;
    if (lim_inf <= x && x <= lim_sup)
    {
         return x;
    }
    else {
         printf("X não está entre lim_inf e lim_sup");
         return 0;
    }
}
```